# Android LinearLayout Asymmetric Centering

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

In the below layout, how can I make sure `blue_view` is centered horizontally on the screen (i.e. its left edge and right edge are perfectly aligned with `red_view`)?

I know there are ways to do this with `ConstraintLayout` and `RelativeLayout`. I was curious if there was a way to accomplish this with `LinearLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/blue_view"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/green_view"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/green"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/red_view"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Image of layout currently**:

[image]

**Desired layout**:

[image]

Comment: will you elaborate more ? What you want to do ?

Comment: I want the blue view to be centered horizontally on the screen. But I'm trying to do it inside the linear layout as shown above.

Comment: Please use ConstraintLayout. [ref1](https://dzone.com/articles/constraintlayout-align-one-views-edge-to-another-v) and [ref2](https://gist.github.com/writtmeyer/f5971266394b2316eb01b566cdeff2a0).

Comment: I know there are ways to do this with `ConstraintLayout` and `RelativeLayout`. I was curious if there was a way to accomplish this with `LinearLayout`.

Comment: I think you are mistaking `center_vertical` with `center_horizontal`

Comment: @KaranMer, I'm not sure what you mean? I want the blue view to be centered horizontally the way the red view is.

Comment: @AdamJohns can you add some pic/drawing of what you want ?

Comment: @AdamJohns : you need to set gravity to `center` your linear layout with blue view, it will pass gravity to child views inside it.

Comment: @Redman, pic of desired layout added.

Comment: also, linear layout doesnt provide type of alignment you want by default, however you can set the margin_start for both the views to match their starting position.

Comment: don't give exact width an height in number Use match_parent or wrap_content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have look on this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/blue_view"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/green_view"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/green"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/red_view"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

OutPut:- [image]

it may be solve your problems....

It is all about adding    `android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"` beacuse you have given `marginRight="20dp"` to its one `childView` and another `childView` is taking `50dp` of center size .

Comment: I'd like to avoid the hardcoded knowledge of 35dp being half of 50+20.

Comment: Just check Edit Answer and check in all the device. It will work 100% @james

Comment: @AdamJohns then use the `RelativeLayout` or `ConstraintLayout`. LinearLayout works sequentially of its child View in Horizontally or Vertically. If you don't want to use both `ViewGroup` then you have to do these calculation in `LinearLayout`

Comment: Fair enough, guess this is the only way for linear layout. Accepted.

Comment: Make an answer unacceptable and try bouty. May be someone give you more information and may be i also get something new to learn?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do with padding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="70dp">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/blue_view"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/green_view"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@color/colorRed" />
    </LinearLayout>

  <View
    android:id="@+id/red_view"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@color/colorGreen" />


 </LinearLayout>
```

add as much padding the extra space it is taking over bottom view, in this case 20 margin and 50 of second view so total 70

**output:**

[image]

Also I don't think there is a way to do it with `LinearLayout` without hardcoding